# Problems with including ExtReact theming

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extreact

I had a problem following  [including theming in ExtReact project](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.5.2/guides/theming.html). 
I did all of offered steps:

> npm install -g @extjs/reactor # adds ext-react cli to your path
>
> ext-react generate theme --name my-theme

and i put:

```
new ExtReactWebpackPlugin({
  theme: './ext-react/packages/my-theme'
})
```

inside of **webpack.config.dev.js** and inside of **webpack.config.dev.js**

but still, it doesn't work. what do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

JUST DO:

**npm install**

after that!

pure simple **npm install** will finish job for you.